# Rearranging nodes and edges in a graph in networkx

Tags: plot, networkx, graph-theory

I plotted the graph below using the spectral layout of networkx (Python). It looks like the same graph could be rearranged into a 3D cube, where the hierarchical relationships would be clearer. All the ones subscripted "orth" can be on the same plane, that is lower than all those subscripted "lex" (which are themselves all on one plane); that is lower than all those subscripted "sem" (which also occupy the same plane).

I have two questions: are there any plotting layouts that would make the hierarchical nature obvious? If the planar structure I described above does that job, how do I implement it?

Code is below:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()


edges = [('$x_{orth}$', '$e_{orth}$'),\
     ('$r_{orth}$', '$e_{orth}$'),\
     ('$e_{orth}$', '$y_{lex}$'),\
     ('$r_{lex}$', '$x_{orth}$'), \
     ('$y_{lex}$', '$r_{orth}$'), \
     ('$y_{lex}$', '$x_{lex}$'), \
     ('$y_{lex}$', '$y_{lex}$'),\

     ('$x_{lex}$', '$e_{lex}$'),\
     ('$r_{lex}$', '$e_{lex}$'),\
     ('$e_{lex}$', '$y_{sem}$'),\
     ('$r_{sem}$', '$x_{lex}$'), \
     ('$y_{sem}$', '$r_{lex}$'), \
     ('$y_{sem}$', '$x_{sem}$'), \
     ('$y_{sem}$', '$y_{sem}$'), \

     ('$x_{sem}$', '$e_{sem}$'),\
     ('$r_{sem}$', '$e_{sem}$'),\
     ('$e_{sem}$', '$y_{mng}$'),\
     ('$y_{mng}$', '$r_{sem}$'), \
     ('$y_{mng}$', '$y_{mng}$')]

G.add_edges_from(edges)


# separate calls to draw nodes and edges
pos = nx.spectral_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos,node_size = 500)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=edges, edge_color='black', arrows=True)
plt.show()
enter code here
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share the edgelist of this graph so we can reproduce?

Comment: @yatu I added the edgelist (and the rest of the code)

Comment: It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but for a more hierarchical layout you could try with `graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out. Unfortunately, the result was not more intuitive than the above.